# Processing json array with jq and quoted values

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I'm attempting to write a script that does some processing on an array of json objects.  A simplified version of the source json looks like this. Note the escaped double quotes in the second object.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1a-2b",
    "name": "my job name",
    "description": "my job description"
  },
  {
    "id": "3c-4d",
    "name": "my \"quoted\" job name",
    "description": "my \"quoted\" job description"
  }
]
```

My script currently attempts to iterate through the source using a 'while read' idiom I found elsewhere in my searches that looks like this.

```
while read job; do

  # fetch individual values into variables
  jobname=`echo $job | jq -r '.name'`

  # do processing on the individual values
  echo $jobname

done < <(cat jobs | jq -c '.[]')
```

The problem seems to be that the escaped quotes get unescaped in the compact output and subsequently the $job variable.  So when I reprocess the individual object with jq inside the loop, I get a jq parse error on each object that has quoted values.

I'm currently using jq 1.4 and I've been trying various combinations of tojson/fromjson/@sh/tostring, but haven't found the right combination yet.  I'm not opposed to moving to jq 1.5 if it has a feature that will make this easier.  I'm also not married to the 'while read' idiom if there is a smarter way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's not quite the right `while`/`read` idiom. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Specifically try `while IFS= read -r; do` and `echo "$job" | ...` and see if that helps. `jq` is doing the right thing probably. Your shell snippet is blowing it all up on you. Try just the `jq` command for example. Also if `jq` takes a filename directly then `<(jq -c '.[]' jobs)` is slightly better.

Comment: It looks like the Bash FAQ link didn't get processed right.  But adding the '-r' to the read definitely fixed the problem.  If you feel like expanding your comment further into an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: Link works now. I bungled it before my edit though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling `jq` again on each array element, just fetch the name with the first call that feeds the loop.

```
 while read -r job; do
     echo "$job"
 done < <(jq -c '.[].name' < jobs)
```

(and use `read -r` as suggested by Etan).

---

If you need multiple variables, try (for example)

```
while read -r id
      read -r job; do
    echo "$id: $job"
done < <(jq -c '.[]|.id,.name' < jobs)
```

Comment: I would definitely have done this if the only value I needed was the name.  But there are an arbitrary number of fields in the object that I need to get the values for and act upon.

Comment: Ooh, I like the multiple read option instead of calling jq again inside the loop.  The '-r' would have solved the original problem by itself, but this is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line

To review, the json file content (file name is jobs):
`[
  {
    "id": "1a-2b",
    "name": "my job name",
    "description": "my job description"
  },
  {
    "id": "3c-4d",
    "name": "my \"quoted\" job name",
    "description": "my \"quoted\" job description"
  }
]`

jq one liner `jq '.[] | (.name)' jobs`

And the output:

`"my job name"
"my \"quoted\" job name"`