# jq - raw output without evaluating new line character

Tags: jq

The json files that I am processing contain newline characters `\n` in the value fields. For example:
    {
      "a": "b\n"
    }

I am trying to generate csv files that contain output, which includes such values. However, when I try `jq -r '[.a]|@csv'`, I get:

```
"b
"
```

The `\n` character is evaluated. I believe this is how `-r` option is intended to work, so I tried the output without it,`jq '[.a]|@csv'`, and I get:

```
"\"b\n\""
```

This is closer to what I want, but the output is quoted and csv-quotes are escaped. My desired output is:

> "b\n"

This becomes troublesome on my actual files, because my csv output contains values with double quotes.

For example:

```
{
  "a": "She said: \"Yes!\"\n",
  "b": "We said: \"Hello!\"\n"
}
```

My desired output in this case is:

> "She said: \"Yes!\"\n","We said: \"Hello!\"\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to escape the newline characters. They are valid JSON characters so it won't be treated differently.

```
[.a, .b] | map(sub("\n"; "\\n")) | @csv
```

This would give you

```
"She said: ""Yes!""\n","We said: ""Hello!""\n"
```

Note that the inner quotes are doubled, that's how you escape double quotes within a CSV line. It is not escaped using backslashes.

In case there are multiple `\n` symbols then using `gsub` instead of `sub` will do the trick.

Comment: Jeff - Wouldn't "gsub" be more appropriate?

Comment: @peak: Yes, in my case `gsub` is more appropriate. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to a related question ([Processing json array with jq and quoted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125603/processing-json-array-with-jq-and-quoted-values?rq=1)), I can do the following:

```
 while read -r a; read -r b; do echo "$a,$b"; done < <(jq -c '.'a,.b test.txt)
```

This gives:

> "She said: \"Yes!\"\n","We said: \"Hello!\"\n"

This is not very general, though, since it must be adjusted to fit the number of fields.